# Testing a class which preserves its state in private variables

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for my class. This class preserves its state in some `private` variables (which I don't want to expose publicly). So the scenario is:

- If I call a method, the first time it will keep that state in `private` properties and call a delegate method with some result.
- When I call the same method a second time, the output will be different on the basis of the previous input.

I want to cover all the cases in my tests.

- One easy way is to change my private properties to public so that I can mock the previous input in unit test.
- The other way is to call the same method with different inputs in the same test twice. Where the first call will keep the state and the next call will be the actual test.

But both these ways seem awkward to me, and I am not sure of the best one.
What is the best way to write unit test for this class?

```
protocol ZoneUpdateDetectorOutput: class {
    func updateZoneState(_ state: ZoneState)
}

class ZoneUpdateDetector {
    var zoneChangeTimer: TimerProtocol?
    weak var delegate: ZoneUpdateDetectorOutput?

    private var previousZoneState: ZoneState?
    private var expectedZoneState: ZoneState?

    private func updateZoneState() {
        // If `expectedZoneState` is not equal to `previousZoneState` then `delegate` will be called
        // Otherwise it will just skip
        if expectedZoneState != previousZoneState {
            delegate?.updateZoneState(expectedZoneState!)
            previousZoneState = expectedZoneState
        }
    }

    private func runNotifyZoneStateTimer() {
        guard zoneChangeTimer?.isValid() == false else {
            return
        }
        zoneChangeTimer?.start(timeInterval: 5,
                               onFire: { [weak self] in
                                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                                    return
                                }
                                // On timer fire, it will try to update the state
                                strongSelf.updateZoneState()
        })
    }

    // When zone changes, this method is invoked
    // I basically want to test this method
    func zoneStateChanged(_ state: ZoneState) {
        expectedZoneState = state
        if state != .inZone {
            runNotifyZoneStateTimer()
        } else {
            zoneChangeTimer?.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you give some more details about what this class is and does, we might be able to suggest a more testable design.

Comment: Sure, I'll add some detail in my question.

Comment: I hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and discussing with some experts, I come up with the solution that if we want to test a class which preserve it's state then the functionality which is preserving the state should go under a separate class. Which will serve the same purpose as setting the variables as private. So, `ZoneUpdateDetector` should have a dependency for example: `ZoneUpdateStatePreserver` and it should keep the state which was previously inside `ZoneUpdateDetector`

Answer (score 2):

You should never be testing internal state; you should only test externally (publically) visible behaviour. That way, you can change implementation details of your class without breaking any contracts, and thus without breaking any tests.

So the second option is the preferred one.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to adopt the second option but I am a bit confused either that is a standard way of doing or not :)