# How can I unit test project level apis of a target in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

I want to write unit test for apis of my target (Say ABC). I have created a unit test target to suffice this (Sav ABCTests). Now I am able to test the public headers of my target (ABC) but not the project and private headers of it. Since the project that I am working on is a SDK and not an app , I cannot make every header public.

The problem that I am facing is that I am not able to import project/private headers.
I am using XCode 10 and Objective-C .

Comment: What's the problem doing so?

Comment: Not able to import project level headers in Test target(i.e. ABCTests)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unit tests a private or internal function in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296564/how-to-unit-tests-a-private-or-internal-function-in-swift)

Comment: there is no such thing as @testable import module in objective c. This will not help in obj c.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, don't `@import` your target API as a module. Instead, `#import` the specific headers you want.

Comment: The problem is that via #import , project level headers are not accessible in test target(i.e. ABCTests)

Comment: Yes . The output of the project is .framework and not .app

Comment: I just created a little framework, ABC. Its tests can `#import` any header they want from the framework, even if the header is marked private. I don't understand what's stopping you from doing the same. Have you tried creating a brand-new framework as an experiment?

Comment: I tried creatingg the new framework and it worked, Thanks Jon. Can you tell what build setting could  have caused that ?

Comment: No, I've never encountered the problem you describe. I'd recommend carefully comparing the new framework against your existing one. At worst, you can move your code into the new network and try to use it as the new home. Good luck!